# GitHub: see all pull requests made by _others_ on _my own_ repositories

Tags: github

I know I can see pull requests made *by me* on *other people's* repositories:

https://github.com/pulls

But I am looking for the opposite. I know there are open pull requests by other people on my repositories. But I have so many repositories, it costs me too much effort to walk through all of them to review open requests.

Is there not a simple search that lists all those pull requests?

Comment: I requested this feature before these nice filters to exist. I was so happy when they implemented them. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GitHub issues filters](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/):

```
is:open is:pr user:username -author:username
```

This will fetch the pull requests made in *your* repositories, by *others* (excluding you, using `-author:username`).

In my case (my username is [`IonicaBizau`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau)) I just do: [`is:open is:pr user:IonicaBizau -author:IonicaBizau`](https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+user%3AIonicaBizau+-author%3AIonicaBizau)